# Multithreading not taking advantage of multiple cores?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading

My computer is a dual core core2Duo. I have implemented multithreading in a slow area of my application but I still notice cpu usage never exceeds 50% and it still lags after many iterations. Is this normal? I was hopeing it would get my cpu up to 100% since im dividing it into 4 threads. Why could it still be capped at 50%?

Thanks

See [What am I doing wrong? (multithreading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190158/what-am-i-doing-wrong-multithreading)

for my implementation, except I fixed the issue that that code was having

Comment: How have you "implemented multithreading"? And how did you identify this segment as the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: May be somewhat obvious but does the process even have the rights to use more than 1 core? (Check in task manager)

Comment: Yes it is allowed, and basically I divide the work into 4 and run my algorithm on multiple threads, I identified it because removing it made things muchhhhhhh faster

Comment: Having multiple threads of execution does not necessarily make your application faster.  For example, in a [false sharing](http://www.ddj.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=217500206) scenario, adding multiple threads can cause a dramatic decrease in performance.

Comment: Dude, you need to provide waaaaay more information. All this question qualifies for a the moment is a "Are you *really* 100% sure it's a Core 2 Duo!!???"

Comment: @user146780:  You are performing a ton of heap allocations; if this process is done in a tight loop, you'll definitely see a performance hit.  Consider using a `std::array` or `boost::array` in place of the inner `vector` since it always has two elements.  Also, you should try and size the outer vector appropriately before you push elements into it so that you can limit the number of reallocations that are performed.  Remember that the general purpose heap allocator _may_ use a global lock, thus potentially obliterating any performance gains you might get from multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are making a huge number of allocations in your tight loop--in each iteration you dynamically allocate two, two-element vectors and then push those back onto the result vector (thus making copies of both of those vectors); that last push back will occasionally cause a reallocation and a copy of the vector contents.

Heap allocation is relatively slow, even if your implementation uses a fast, fixed-size allocator for small blocks.  In the worst case, the general-purpose allocator may even use a global lock; if so, it will obliterate any gains you might get from multithreading, since each thread will spend a lot of time waiting on heap allocation.

Of course, profiling would tell you whether heap allocation is constraining your performance or whether it's something else.  I'd make two concrete suggestions to cut back your heap allocations:

- Since every instance of the inner vector has two elements, you should consider using a `std::array` (or `std::tr1::array` or `boost::array`); the `array` "container" doesn't use heap allocation for its elements (they are stored like a C array).
- Since you know roughly how many elements you are going to put into the result vector, you can `reserve()` sufficient space for those elements before inserting them.

Answer (score 1):

From your description we have very little to go on, however, let me see if I can help:

2. You have implemented a lock-based system but you aren't judiciously using the resources of the second, third, or fourth threads because the entity that they require is constantly locked. (this is a very real and obvious area I'd look into first)
3. You're not actually using more than a single thread.  Somehow, somewhere, those other threads aren't even fired up or initialized. (sounds stupid but I've done this before)

Look into those areas first.

Comment: Call stack says theres 4 threads running, also none of the threads ever access the same element.

Comment: @user146780: I am unsure how you work out the number of running threads by looking at a call stack. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Well I added a giant for loop and got the cpu up to 100%, but as  James McNellis has just told me I think im doing too many heap allocations